# Python console keeps popping up in Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows-10, python, sublime-text-3

I have configured installation of Sublime Text 3 in one of my Windows machines. Now, I used PackageSyncing to sync packages to another installation of ST3 on another Windows machine. (Both are Windows 10 machines.)

But on the new installation, whenever I click into a new file tab or save using ctrl+s, a new `pythonw.exe` console pops up. It goes away in a few seconds, so I am unable to even debug it to some extent, and I don't know if some package is causing it because it is working just fine in the old installation.

Does anyone also has encountered this issue, or know to reach the root of it?

IMPORTANT: The console is not the default python console, but located inside `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\`.

Comment: What happens if you rename, or simply delete `C:\Program Files\chocolatey\bin\pythonw.exe`?

Comment: What if messes up the `chocolatey` installation?

Comment: Why do you have Python installed through Chocolatey anyway, if you already have a "default" Python (I'm assuming from python.org)? At any rate, I've been programming with Python for many years, and I've never found a use for `pythonw.exe`. You can learn more about the difference between it and `python.exe` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9705982/1426065).

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. Also, I made a mistake, it was in `ProgramData`, not `Program Files`. And, I don't have python installed via Chocolatey, that is choco's own python executable, I guess(?). I read your link, but my problem is not linked to python, but its that ST3 is popping up consoles on save/click!